# Reading values to array, inside a loop

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, object

I am trying to build a program which allows a user to input an actors name and details (age+address) and also 2 films they've starred in. These films must be read into a main array in the main method, but each individual actors films must be copied into a designated array in my actor class to store the actors films individually.

I am currently trying to read the values into my array inside a loop in my main method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        String code="";

        System.out.println("How many actors would you like to enter?");

        int amt = kbd.nextInt();
        int noOfFilms = (amt*2);

        Actor [] arrayOfActors = new Actor[amt];

        //Array of ALL films, each actors films must be copied to seperate array in the actor class.
        String [] allFilms = new String[noOfFilms];

        kbd.nextLine();

        int count = 1;
        int i = 0;

        do {
            count++;

            System.out.println("Enter the Details for actor "+(count-1)+"\n");

            System.out.println("Enter actor name:"+"\n");
            String name = kbd.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter actor age:"+"\n");
            int age = kbd.nextInt();

            kbd.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Enter actor address:"+"\n");
            String address = kbd.nextLine();

            //Read in the actors films
            System.out.println("Enter film 1 for "+name+"\n");
            String film1 = kbd.nextLine();
            allFilms[i] = film1;

            System.out.println("Enter film 2 for "+name+"\n");
            String film2 = kbd.nextLine();
            allFilms[i+1] = film2;


            //Create an actor as array is full of references only.
            arrayOfActors[i] = new Actor(name, address, age);
            i++; 

            arrayOfActors[i-1].print();

        } while (count <= amt);

        System.out.println("This was in the films array: "+allFilms[1]);
    }
}
```

Obviously the way I have it structured currently will not work as every time the loop starts the values will just be over-written and the only details stored will be the last actors films to be entered.

I am stuck trying to work around this and read in all the films, which will then need to be deep copied into another array. (in Actor class)

This is a college assignment and must be done this way. Any suggestions would be of great help.

Comment: You might want to look into dynamic lists.

Comment: Can you use java.util.List in your assignment ?

Answer (score 0):

You can include an array field inside your `Actor` class. Then you will modify your `Actor` class constructor in order to include this array argument for initialization purposes.

So I would handle this part inside the loop like this:

```
String[] actorFilms = new String[2];
//Read in the actors films
System.out.println("Enter film 1 for "+name+"\n");
String film1 = kbd.nextLine();
allFilms[i] = film1;      //not OK; read below
actorFilms[0] = film1;    
System.out.println("Enter film 2 for "+name+"\n");
String film2 = kbd.nextLine();
allFilms[i+1] = film2;    //not OK; read below
actorFilms[1] = film2;    


//Create an actor as array is full of references only.
arrayOfActors[i] = new Actor(name, address, age, actorFilms);
```

I'm not sure if you still need to keep the `allFilms` array, but if you need, you will have to determine the indexes you need to populate depending on the `count` value. By simply using `i` and `i+1` you always overwrite the same locations in the array.

Some other remarks:
-- I think you're not using `count` properly; you're initializing it with 0, but you immediately increment it (first statement in the loop);
-- notation conventions in Java state that class names should be capitalized.

Comment: The problem is the array with ALL films must be inside the main method. The array in the actor class must only contain the films related to that actor.

Comment: Well, it is in the main method. I don't understand how it should be and isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest use a collection of actor objects in a collection.

Collection actorDetails= new ArrayList<>();

do 
{
....
...

....

actorDetails.add(actioObj)

}while(....)

finally use actorDetails to retriev information

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner (System.in);
        String code = "";
        System.out.println("How many actors would you like to enter?");
        int amt = kbd.nextInt();
        int noOfFilms = (amt * 2);
        Actor[] arrayOfActors = new Actor[amt];
        String[] allFilms = new String[noOfFilms];
        kbd.nextLine();

        for (int count = 0; count < amt; count++) {

            System.out.println("Enter the details for actor " + (count + 1));
            System.out.prinln("Enter actor name:");
            String name = kbd.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter actor age:");
            int age = kbd.nextInt();
            kbd.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter actor address:");
            String address = kbd.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter film 1 for " + name);
            String film1 = kbd.nextLine();
            allFilms[count * 2] = film1;

            System.out.println("Enter film 2 for " + name );
            String film2 = kbd.nextLine();
            allFilms[(count * 2) + 1] = film2;

            arrayOfActors[count] = new Actor(name, address, age);
            arrayOfActors[count].print();

        }

        System.out.println("This was in the films array: " + allFilms[1]);
    }
}
```

Perhaps something like this? I got rid of the *i* variable and used only the *count* variable to keep track of the array indexes. I am assuming you have not began working with Collections, otherwise you could do that.